# Converting Large float64 Matrix into int32 Matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, euclidean-distance

I have a large dataset that I need to calculate the euclidean distance matrix for, however, I am limited on RAM and using np.float64 (default) as dtype makes the PC goes out of memory. I would use the squared distance as it is faster and returns an integer anyhow.

using .astype(np.int32) does not solve the issue as it is still created as float64 first.

**the dataset itself is int32 but the returned matrix is float64**

```py
matrix = pairwise_distances(dataset, metric='euclidean', squared=True)
print(matrix.dtype)
```

```
float64
```

How can I cast it directly as an int array?

Comment: so you want to convert your np.float64 data into np.int32 data ??

Comment: not really, I want to cast the array directly as np.int32

Comment: ah I see, so you need low computational time right ?

Comment: problem is that my RAM is not sufficient to hold float64 elements with this number but can hold int32 without problem

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is you want to make your data RAM efficient

You can convert your return matrix into int32 (consider loss in the data) or float32 which is better 
here's my example code for doing that

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1.0, 4, 5, 12], 
    [-5.9, 8, 9.7, 0],
    [-6, 7, 11, 19]])
print(arr.dtype) 
arr = arr.astype('float32') 
print(arr.dtype)
```

the output were as follows

```
float64
float32
```

Comment: what is the type of the matrix ? ndarray ?

Comment: on real data no because it will not get past the declaration state